# Make an iPhone InfoButton light/dark based on color behind it

Tags: iphone, background, uiimageview, uibutton, uicolor

How do I detect what color is under the InfoButton... so I can change the button
from DARK to LIGHT?

I set my view's color... but how do I tell if it's "kind of light" or "kind of dark"?

Besides... I can't change the info-button from light to dark anyway.  (read only)

Ugh.

Shouldn't Apple have some kind of a simple "cmdButton.doThisExtremelyCommonThingForMe = TRUE" statement?

InfoButtons are useless if you can't even see them.

(Or how would I put an image behind the button to make it stand-out more?)

Comment: What do you expect to be behind this button?  Is it an ImageView or what?  Whatever it is, it should have some way of looking at what pixels are in that region.  Then just take the average brightness of those pixels to determine whether to use the light or dark button.

Answer (score 0):

> but how do I tell if it's "kind of
>   light" or "kind of dark"?

Um, look at it?

> Shouldn't Apple have some kind of a
>   simple
>   "cmdButton.doThisExtremelyCommonThingForMe
>   = TRUE" statement?

Yeah, that would be great. But only if they'd also supply a cmdButton.doThisOtherExtremelyCommonThingForMeToo.